# Can't find Apache Flume log files

Tags: hadoop, flume

I have just made a fresh install of Apache Flume 1.11.0 and have been able to run the sample agent. I am now trying to figure out where Flume creates log files but I can't seem to find it.

It's not in the directory where I am running the agent and it's not in the home directory, It's also not in `/var/log`.

I even created a logs directory in `$FLUME_HOME` and made sure the correct user owned the directory.

This version of flume had a `log4j2.xml` file instead of `log4j.properties`. I modified the `<Property name="LOG_DIR">` tag with an absolute URL, but this didn't fix the problem.

I even tried creating an `log4j.properties` file with no success.

Does Apache flume generate log files? Where can I find them? and why is none of this documented?